# Too many Query Rows 50001-For Atttachment Object

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am getting this error

> Too many query rows error 50001

I perform my query as follows:

```
List <Attachment> lstOfAttachment = Database.query(
    'select Id, Name,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from Attachment order by ' +
    sortFullExp + ' Limit ' + list_size + ' offset ' + counter + ''
);
```

**Markup**

```
<apex:page controller="AttachmentListWithFilterController">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:form id="form" >
        <apex:inputHidden id="selectedF" value="{!selectedFiles}"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="callfind" action="{!searchByRange}" reRender="PGTable" />
        <apex:pageBlock id="pblock" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Filter" collapsible="true" columns="2" id="pbsection">
                <apex:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Owner "/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!attachmentToUser.OwnerId}" required="false"/>                                      
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!searchByOwner}" value="Submit" reRender="PGTable"/> 

                </apex:panelGrid>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <div id="slider-range" style="font-size: 90%; margin-top: 0.5em;"></div>
                        <div id="amountValue" style="text-align: center;"></div>
                 <!--        <apex:commandButton value="searchByRange" action="{!searchByRange}" reRender="PGTable"/>   ---->

            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

               </apex:pageBlockSection>

                  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="values">
                <!-- You could make these fields apex:inputHidden and then use only the slider -->
             <apex:inputHidden value="{!sSliderFieldMin}" id="idInputHiddenMin"/>
             <apex:inputHidden value="{!sSliderFieldMax}" id="idInputHiddenMax"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>               



            <apex:pageblockSection title="All Attachments" collapsible="false" columns="1">
                <apex:outputPanel id="panelid"> 
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listWrap}" var="attWrap" title="All Attachments" id="PGTable">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                        </apex:facet> 
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!attWrap.selected}" id="inputId" onchange="selectThis(this,'{!JSENCODE(attWrap.attach.id)}_')"/>
                    </apex:column> 

               <apex:column value="{!attWrap.attach.Name}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">   
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!viewSortcolumn}" reRender="panelid"   value="Attachment Name{!IF(sortExpression=='name',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort">
                 <apex:param value="name" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
               </apex:commandLink>
               </apex:facet>
               </apex:column>


                <apex:column value="{!attWrap.attach.BodyLength}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">   
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!viewSortcolumn}" reRender="panelid"  value="Attachment Size{!IF(sortExpression=='BodyLength',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort1">
                 <apex:param value="BodyLength" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
                 </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
                 </apex:column>

                <apex:column value="{!attWrap.attach.CreatedDate}">
                  <apex:facet name="header">   
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!viewSortcolumn}" reRender="panelid"  value="CreatedDate{!IF(sortExpression=='CreatedDate',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort2">
                 <apex:param value="CreatedDate" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
                 </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
                 </apex:column>

                    <apex:column value="{!attWrap.attach.Owner.Name}" >
                        <apex:facet name="header">   
                             <apex:commandLink action="{!viewSortcolumn}" reRender="panelid"  value="Owner{!IF(sortExpression=='Owner.Name',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort3">
                             <apex:param value="CreatedBy.Name" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
                             </apex:commandLink>
                             </apex:facet>
                             </apex:column>

                     <apex:column headerValue="(Click to view)" >
                     <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,attWrap.attach.id)}" target="_blank">
                                 View</apex:outputLink>
                     </apex:column>

                     <apex:facet name="footer">Showing Page # {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}</apex:facet>
                </apex:pageBlockTable></apex:outputPanel>
                 <apex:outputPanel id="myButtons">
               <apex:commandButton action="{!Beginning}" title="Beginning" value="<<" disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="panelid,myButtons"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Previous}" title="Previous" value="<" disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="panelid,myButtons"/>        
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" title="Next" value=">" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="panelid,myButtons"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!End}" title="End" value=">>" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="panelid,myButtons"/>        
              </apex:outputPanel>  
                </apex:pageblockSection>
                <center>      <apex:commandButton value="Delete Selected" action="{!deleteSelected}"/>    </center>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class AttachmentListWithFilterController {

    public string selectedFiles { get; set; }
    public String getViewSortcolumn() {
        return null;
    }


    public PageReference ListWrap() {
        return null;
    }

    Public List < Attachment > lstOfAttachment {
        get;
        set;
    }
    Public List < wrapAttachment > lstWrapAttachment {
        get;
        set;
    }
    Public List < Attachment > lstSelectedAttachment {
        get;
        set;
    }
    Public map < string, wrapAttachment > mapIdWrapAtt {
        get;
        set;
    }
    Private String sortDirection = 'ASC';
    Private String sortExp = 'name';
    Public Attachment attachmentToUser {
        get;
        set;
    }
    Public Integer sSliderFieldMin {
        get;
        set;
    }
    Public List < Attachment > lstAttachmentByRange {
        get;
        set;
    }
    Public Integer sSliderFieldMax {
        get;
        set;
    }
    Public String searchByRange {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private integer counter = 0; //keeps track of the offset
    private integer list_size = 10; //sets the page size or number of rows
    public integer total_size; //used to show user the total size of the list
    Public String sortExpression {
        get {
            return sortExp;
        }
        set {
            //if the column is clicked on then switch between Ascending and Descending modes
            if (value == sortExp)
                sortDirection = (sortDirection == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
            else
                sortDirection = 'ASC';
            sortExp = value;
        }
    }
    public String getSortDirection() {
        //if not column is selected 
        if (sortExpression == null || sortExpression == '')
            return 'ASC';
        else
            return sortDirection;
    }

    public void setSortDirection(String value) {
        sortDirection = value;
    }    

    public AttachmentListWithFilterController() {                
        sSliderFieldMin = 0;
        sSliderFieldMax = 25600;
        selectedFiles=null;
        lstAttachmentByRange = new List < Attachment > ();
        mapIdWrapAtt = new Map < string, wrapAttachment > ();
        searchByRange = '';
        lstSelectedAttachment = new List < Attachment > ();
        lstWrapAttachment = new List < wrapAttachment > ();
        attachmentToUser = new Attachment();
        string sortFullExp = sortExpression + ' ' + sortDirection;
        List < Attachment > lstOfAttachment = Database.query('select Id, Name,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from Attachment order by ' + sortFullExp + ' Limit ' + list_size + ' offset ' + counter + '');
        for (Attachment a: lstOfAttachment) {
            wrapAttachment objWrapAtt = new wrapAttachment(a);
            lstWrapAttachment.add(objWrapAtt);
            mapIdWrapAtt.put(a.id, objWrapAtt);
        }
        total_size = [select count() from Attachment where id!=Null]; //set the total size in the constructor  
    }

    public List < wrapAttachment > getListWrap() {
        //Clear the existing list
        lstWrapAttachment.clear();
        string sortFullExp = sortExpression + ' ' + sortDirection;
        String queryList = 'select Id, Name,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from Attachment where BodyLength  >=' + sSliderFieldMin * 1024 + ' AND BodyLength <=' + sSliderFieldMax * 1024;        
        if (attachmentToUser.OwnerId != NULL) {
            queryList += ' AND OwnerId =\'' + attachmentToUser.OwnerId + '\'';
        }
        queryList += ' order by ' + sortFullExp + ' Limit ' + list_size + ' offset ' + counter;
        mapIdWrapAtt = new Map < string, wrapAttachment > ();
        List < Attachment > lstOfAttachment = Database.query(queryList);
        for (Attachment a: lstOfAttachment) {
            wrapAttachment objWrapAtt = new wrapAttachment(a);
            lstWrapAttachment.add(objWrapAtt);
            mapIdWrapAtt.put(a.id, objWrapAtt);
        }
        if(selectedFiles!=null){
            for(String str:selectedFiles.trim().split('_')){
                //Id attId = (Id)str;
                if(str!=null && mapIdWrapAtt.containsKey(str))
                  mapIdWrapAtt.get(str).selected = true;  
            }  
        }
        return lstWrapAttachment;
    }

    public pageReference deleteSelected() {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < lstWrapAttachment.size(); i++) {
            if (lstWrapAttachment[i].selected) {
                lstSelectedAttachment.add(lstWrapAttachment[i].attach);
            }
        }
        if (lstSelectedAttachment.size() > 0) {

            if(!Schema.sObjectType.Attachment.isDeletable())
            {
                 ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'Insufficient access')); 
                 return null;
            }
            else
            {
                delete lstSelectedAttachment;
            }
        }
        Pagereference pg = new pagereference('/apex/AttachmentListWithFilter');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }
    public PageReference viewSortcolumn() {         
        getListWrap();
        return Null;
    }

    Public pagereference searchByOwner() {       
        if(attachmentToUser.OwnerId !=NULL){
             String searchByOwner ='SELECT Name,Id,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from Attachment where OwnerId =\''+attachmentToUser.OwnerId+'\'';  

             List<Attachment> lstAttachmentByOwner= Database.query(searchByOwner);
             lstWrapAttachment.clear();
             for(Attachment a:lstAttachmentByOwner){
                 lstWrapAttachment.add(new WrapAttachment(a));
             }
             total_size =  lstWrapAttachment.size();
        }
        return null;
    }

    Public pagereference searchByRange() {     
        searchByRange = 'SELECT Name,Id,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from Attachment';
        searchByRange += ' where BodyLength  >=' + sSliderFieldMin * 1024 + ' AND BodyLength <=' + sSliderFieldMax * 1024;


        if (attachmentToUser.OwnerId != NULL) {
            searchByRange += ' AND OwnerId =\'' + attachmentToUser.OwnerId + '\'';
        }

        lstAttachmentByRange = Database.query(searchByRange);
        lstWrapAttachment.clear();
        for (Attachment searchedList: lstAttachmentByRange) {
            lstWrapAttachment.add(new WrapAttachment(searchedList));
        }
        total_size =  lstWrapAttachment.size();
        //getListWrap();
        return null;
    }    
    /*PAGINATION-----*/
    public PageReference Beginning() { //user clicked beginning
        counter = 0;
        getListWrap();
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference Previous() { //user clicked previous button
        counter -= list_size;
        getListWrap();
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference Next() { //user clicked next button
        counter += list_size;
        getListWrap();
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference End() { //user clicked end
        counter = total_size - math.mod(total_size, list_size);
        getListWrap();
        return null;
    }

    public Boolean getDisablePrevious() {
        //this will disable the previous and beginning buttons
        if (counter > 0) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public Boolean getDisableNext() { //this will disable the next and end buttons
        if (counter + list_size < total_size) return false;
        else return true;
    }    

    public Integer getPageNumber() {
        if(total_size==0)
            return 0;
        return counter / list_size + 1;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPages() {
        if (math.mod(total_size, list_size) > 0) {
            //Integer i = Integer.valueOf('in'+total_size / list_size + 1);
            return total_size / list_size + 1;
        } else {
            //Integer i = Integer.valueOf('out'+total_size);
            return (total_size / list_size);
        }
    }


    /*----------------*/

    public class wrapAttachment {

        public Attachment attach {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Boolean selected {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Integer sizeInKiloByte {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public wrapAttachment(Attachment objAttachment) {
            //  BodyLength = objAttachment.BodyLength/1024;
            attach = objAttachment;
            selected = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any Possibility of Governor Limit??

Answer (score 0):

This line is making your code break. You should limit the size of this list to a certain number and then check for the value stored in count(). If it's equal to your limit, display something like more than XXX records in the total size.

> `total_size = [select count() from Attachment where id!=Null]; //set the total size in the constructor`
>
> `total_size = [select count() from Attachment LIMIT 40000]; //set the total size in the constructor`

Comment: It Still giving me error